# Show that the following argument is valid.

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Can anyone help me solve the above problem please? I am stuck for hours.

[image]

Comment: Hi, welcome on MSE. :) What have you tried?

Comment: @InsideOut I haven't tried anything really, because I really dont know how to solve it and I can't find anything on google either.

Comment: I guess $p\to q$ means $p \Longrightarrow q$, right? Do you know how $\Longrightarrow$ is defined?

Comment: No, I for real don't know anything about it. I need a tutorial I guess.

Comment: I see, usually this a basic exercise of logic. Does your teacher give you this exercise? Probably is based on what you have done before.

Comment: I have a possible answer based on my guessing that it is an exercise of logic. But, if this exercise comes from another topic, without further informations is quite difficult to provide an answer.

Comment: [Context](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question) helps other people answer your question. Can you tell us where the question comes from, or which class did you find this question in?

Comment: *modus ponens*?

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown Problem is that the OP doesn't seem to know the context of problem. If it was logic, modus ponens would lead to the answer